# Multiple PeopleEditors create horrendous error

Tags: people-picker

I am trying to use multiple PeopleEditors that i create programmatically during init and prerender. (It is vital that I create them at prerender) 
The error only occours when multiple PE get created at prerender.
Creating only one PeopleEditor works fine. Multiple just plain break some kind of Javascript in the background.

I was unable to find any info on this error.

I am really grateful for any kind of insight!

Thanks

Comment: Alright, I found the solution.

I manually set the ID of the PeopleEditors and they contained a ";". This caused problems with the javascript that is connected to the PeopleEditor.

So just don't use ; in your IDs...

Comment: Post this as an answer instead as soon as you can, that way you can closer the question properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution. I manually set the ID of the PeopleEditors and they contained a ";". This caused problems with the javascript that is connected to the PeopleEditor. So just don't use ; in your IDs...